# Why are there so many Java files in my "All My Files" section in Finder

Tags: macos, finder

Any time I try to open the section "All My Files", it takes a long time to load because it has so many of these files on it:

[image: Too many files]

I believe there are several thousand of these files. The only thing that I can think of is that these files might be from Eclipse, a Java editor (I am learning to code in Java). How do I make them go away without messing anything up? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stop auto saving them. You are the only one who can decide which one to delete.

Comment: How do I stop auto saving them? (sorry, I'm new to OS X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse preferences choose whether to auto-save or not.

Instructions found here http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Frun-debug%2Fref-launching.htm

and here
http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/10/26/top-10-tips-how-to-be-more-productive-with-the-best-ide/

[image: eclipse save]

Comment: Ok, I unchecked the "Save automatically before build" box. Now, is there any way I can contain the files already there? I don't really want to delete anything because they might be required for eclipse to work.

Comment: Not in All my Files view, that one will always show all files on the disk regardless of the folder they are in. To narrow them down use the Date created column in Finder (right click on the finders bar and select it) in that view. That will group them by created date (where you can assume all the same but save the last one for that date + time.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help, and I think as far as hiding all the files, I will just remove the "All My Files" view from Finder.

Comment: one way of doing it :)

Answer (score 1):

1. open System Preferences, click on Spotlight, then Privacy. leave this window open and proceed to the next step.
2. in Finder, open the folder where the Eclipse files are stored, then drag this folder into the Spotlight-Privacy window you opened in step 1. alternatively, you can press the + button at the bottom of the Privacy pane to add files & folders to exclude.

voila, the offending files should have disappearred from All My Files. Spotlight doesn't index any files that are listed under Privacy, thus excluding them from an All My Files search.

tip: if you're not sure in which folder the Eclipse files are stored, then right-click on any one of those files and choose Show in Enclosing Folder. a new Finder window will open.